# Yii2 firebase, how create user account on firebase and linking Identity Providers

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, yii2

I try to create user on firebase used google auth. I used this: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

The first thing I do is I just create a user in the system. `createUser` working fine.

Then I try to add to it linking Identity Providers that is, I am trying to indicate that the user was registered through Google. That's what the documentation says, and that's exactly what I'm doing.

[image]

[image: provider example]

But i have error like

```
INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Unsuccessful check authorization response from Google: {
  "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

my controller action

```
/**
     * @return yii\web\Response
     * @throws yii\base\InvalidConfigException
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function actionSocial()
    {
        $token = $this->getParam(Yii::$app->request, 'token');
        $firebase = new Firebase();
        $verifiedIdToken = $firebase->verifyIdToken($token);    

        if (!$verifiedIdToken) {
            return $this->errorResponse(400, 'Token not valid');
        }

        $uid = $verifiedIdToken->getClaim('sub');
        $email = $verifiedIdToken->getClaim('email');

        $firebaseUser = $firebase->getDataByUid($uid);
        if(!$firebaseUser){
            $result = $firebase->createUserSocial($token, $uid, $email);
            //todo register user on firebase and our system
        }
        
        //todo other logic here
    }
```

my method createUserSocial

```
    public function createUserSocial($token, $uid, $email)
    {
        try {

            $properties = [
                'uid' => $uid,
                'email' => $email,
            ];

            $user = $this->firebaseAuth->createAuth()->createUser($properties);
            $this->firebaseAuth->createAuth()->signInWithIdpAccessToken('google.com', $token);
            return $user;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```